# Ldap user authentication failure with invalid Credentials

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a ldap server which is configured like this:
`cn=adminuser,dc=compnay,dc=com`
Then i have ccreate `ou=users`.
I want to add some users to this `ou` with the intention of authenticating them from my `python` application.
so the tree looks something like this:

```
* cn=adminuser,dc=compnay,dc=com
  * users
     - sam
     - Laurie
     - Joe
```

with some attributes assigned to all users like `mobile`, `email`.
When i want to authenticate the users from the user form, i cannot bind using the `connection(user='ou=users,cn=sam,dc=company,dc=com',password=mypassword)`
I have assigned `password` & `cn` to all users.

**Expected**: 
Users will get authenticated.

**Output**:
`Bind error.invalidCredentials`

When i use the full `DN` in `connection()` ex`ou=groups,cn=sam,mobile=xxxxx,email=sam@sam.com`, it works but obvously i cannot ask each user to enter all details while authenticating,
is there any mistake in my understanding of user authentication via ldap?

NOTE i am using python `ldap3` library.

Comment: Can you add one of your users entry as an example (e.g. with `ldapsearch -b "dc=company,dc=com"`)?  Your users should just enter their `uid` and you should transform it into something like `uid=<uid>,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com`.

Comment: Or depending on the type of the LDAP server you use (Active Directory?) you may use other attributes (like `sAMAccountName`).